# SQL Server CE Insert with Data Directory

Tags: c#, deployment, sql-server-ce

I have created a simple C# application that stores some info in a SQL Server CE database, searches for a specific row etc... I can read from the database without any problem, but inserting data into it isn't going as smoothly.

I checked many sources online, and what I got is that I can't use this connection string:

```
SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf");
```

because `|DataDirectory|` in this case works with reading from the database, but not with inserting. What I should do according to online sources is use a hard-coded path for the database, i.e. :

```
SqlCeConnection connection1 = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Database1.sdf");
```

However, if I do this, it will cause major deployment program because the hard-coded path won't be the same on all the machines. Please any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you link the source of this information? And are we talking about a WinForms project or ASP.NET

Comment: Also could you verify if it is just a case of wrong settings on Server Explorer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887992/c-sharp-sql-server-ce-not-inserting/19888060#19888060

Comment: You could easily store the full path to the database file into a **config** file ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the hard-coded path in debugging and `|DataDirectory|` in deployment as below.

```
SqlCeConnection connection;

if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Database1.sdf");
}
else
{
    connection = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf");
}
```